# How to insert values 1-100 into redis with python script using for loop?

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to insert 100 values into Redis via a Python script, the data type doesn't matter.

I've tried using a list, but how can you increment the values in the list (doesn't accept strings) other than doing it manually. Ex:

```
r.lpush list 1    
r.lpush list 2   
etc.
```

I don't want to have to type out 100 `lpush`'s. How can this be done in a loop?

I've tried using strings and incrementing the strings, but I would have to keep changing the value. Ex:

```
set key 1   
set key2 2  
set key3 3
```

So how in the world can I get values 1-100 inserted into redis so that I can read them off?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis( url='rediss://:password@hostname:port/0',
    password='password',
    ssl_keyfile='path_to_keyfile',
    ssl_certfile='path_to_certfile',
    ssl_cert_reqs='required',
    ssl_ca_certs='path_to_ca_certfile')

for i in range(1,100):
    r.set('foo{}'.format(i), 'bar{}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? Is it making a list and entering 100 values into the list? There seems to be little information about various commands within the redis documentation

Comment: The code generates 99 different keys [foo1,foo2,...] and 99 different values [bar1,bar2,...]. The pairs [key,value] are pushed into redis. If you want to poulate a list you can use `r.lpush('MyList', [str(i) for in range(1,100)])`

Comment: The "i" declaration is missing in the for loop. `for i in range(1,100):
    r.set('foo{}'.format(i), 'bar{}'.format(i))`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    r.lpush("list", str(i))
```

`range(1, 101)` generates integers from `1` (inclusive) to `101` (exclusive), `str(i)` changes `i` (e. g . `57`) to the string (e. g. `"57"`).

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with the following python code to input values 0 - 100 into Redis

```
i = 1
while(i < 101):
    r.rpush('value', i)
    i += 1

#Print out the values from 1 - 100  
print(r.lrange('value', 0, -1))
```

Thanks everyone!